# Representing Equivalence Relations with Nodes, Loops, and Edges

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, arrows, graphs, tikz-arrows

I've never used TikZ for illustrating equivalence relations, but I thought I'd try it out. What I'd like to produce is something like this:

[image: output]

What is the general method for connecting points to themselves with looped arrows and creating labels of the points to the right?

---

So here is what I used to solve [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470692/r-subset-s-times-s-for-s-1-2-3-a-graph-theoretic-approach) problem:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm,
  thick,main node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]

  \node[main node] (1) {1};
  \node[main node] (2) [right of=1] {2};
  \node[main node] (3) [right of=2] {3};

  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1) edge [bend right] node [left] {} (2)
        edge [bend right] node[left] {} (3)
        edge [loop above] node {} (1)
    (2) edge [loop above] node {} (2)
    (3) edge [loop above] node {} (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

I got the idea from [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/graph/).

Comment: Also, points to points.

Comment: I think you should strt from the examples in the manual first. There are many examples there and in Texample.net and here on the site

Comment: I'll check that out.

Comment: Nice. Can you post that as an answer? So this question is archived as solved. (It needs 24 hours before you can accept your own answer I think though).

Comment: Hi, sorry to nag, but would you mind doing as percusse suggested? There's nothing wrong with answering ones own question.

Answer (score 2):

One of many approaches.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  >=stealth,
  start chain=n going right,
  every edge/.append style={shorten >=+1pt, /utils/exec=\scriptsize}]
\foreach \cnt in {1,...,4}
  \node [circle, fill=blue!20, draw, on chain=n] {\cnt}
    edge [loop above] node {$x_{\cnt,\cnt}$} ();

\path[->, bend right] (n-1) edge node[above]           {$x_{1,2}$} (n-2)
                            edge node[above, near end] {$x_{1,3}$} (n-3)
                            edge node[above, pos=.875] {$x_{1,4}$} (n-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]